# FastReport 5.6.2 - Porque não gerou os arquivos .bpl

Tags: instalador, delphi-10, fast-reports, delphi-tokyo

Realizei os Procedimentos para instalar o *FastReport* no *Delphi 10.2* Compilo os fontes do *FastReport* mas os arquivos ***.bpl*** não aparece na Pasta.
O que deve ser feito?

Segui esses passos:

1. Na pasta do *FastReport* Exulto o *recompile.exe* em modo de Administrador.
2. Add a pasta LibD25 em : *Tools - Options - Environment Options - Delphi Options - Library - Library path*.
3. Instalar os Componentes em: *Component - Install Packages...*
4. Em *Install Packages* Add e seleciona todos os arquivos .bpl e Open.

e aqui no item 4 é que eu paro pois não tem os arquivos... O que devo fazer?